# How do I code a grid-like function into Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, input, grid, output

Problem:  ACL  Scrabble is a lettered tile game played on a grid game board.  The board for this program will be 4 x 10.  The grid squares are numbered as below:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
    11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
    21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30
    31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
```

The squares that are every other multiple of 3 (3, 9, 15...) are Double Letter score squares.

The squares that are multiples of 5 and not used above are Triple Letter score squares.

The squares that are multiples of 7 and not used above are Double Word score squares.

The squares that are multiples of 8 and not used above are Triple Word score squares.

Letter values will come from the following chart:

```
            A, E - 1 point
            D, R - 2 points
            B, M - 3 points
            V, Y - 4 points
            J, X - 8 points
```

INPUT:  There will be 6 lines of input.  The first line will give the letters of the word.  The word will always have 4 letters.  The remaining 5 lines will be starting locations for the word and a direction:  horizontal (H) or vertical (V).

OUTPUT:  For each starting location, print the total points scored by the word.  No word will have more than one word score multiplier

```
    SAMPLE INPUT                    SAMPLE OUTPUT
    1.   J, A, V, A                 1.  18
    2.   1, V                       2.  17
    3.   2, H                       3.  42
    4.   6, V                       4.  30
    5.  12, H                       5.  66
    6.  21, H
```

My question: How would I go about doing such a task? What's the most efficient way? Should I assign each letter to a number and just code in a bunch of if statements or is there another way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: Make a tile object with point value and put them into 2D array

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use a 2D Array (representing x and y locations) to store values in a grid-like structure.

> The squares that are every other multiple of 3 (3, 9, 15...) are Double Letter score > squares.
>
> The squares that are multiples of 5 and not used above are Triple Letter score squares.
>
> The squares that are multiples of 7 and not used above are Double Word score squares.
>
> The squares that are multiples of 8 and not used above are Triple Word score squares.

When checking for "bonus" values, try using a for statement to check whether or not a given value is within the set of bonus values.

> ```
> SAMPLE INPUT                    SAMPLE OUTPUT
> 1.   J, A, V, A                 1.  18
> 2.   1, V                       2.  17
> 3.   2, H                       3.  42
> 4.   6, V                       4.  30
> 5.  12, H                       5.  66
> 6.  21, H
> ```

For the required output, simply check the value of each input and add it to the previous value.

This looks like a homework question to me, so I won't  post any code.